# Do not refresh after click on row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have problem here to make it do not refresh after I click on row to submit a value from row of table.

This is working version with clicking and submitting, but its reloading a page

[Example on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nyn2n4t/7/)

And this is I'm trying to make to do not reload, but its not working:

```
$("table").on('click','tr',function(e){
$('#img').show();
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
//    alert(id);
var $form = $('#leagueForm');
// set the input value
$(function () {
  $('#club2').val(id);
});
$form.submit(){
$('#js-trigger-overlay').click(function(){
        $.post("index.php",
            {club2: $('#club2').val()},
            function(data){
                $('#response').html(data);
            }
        );

    });
});
});
```

Comment: post your html here

Comment: @JayeshChitroda you have it on the link of jsfiddle. That is my html, check it

Comment: your $form.submit(); submitts the form and reloads page. you can add the $('form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); }); to kill the submit and run an ajax call if that is what you want.

Comment: add `return false;` in the click function..which avoids the refresh...Or e.preventdefault();

Comment: yes but my ajax doesnt working right, i cannot got nothing in response table

Comment: use input type button instead of submit and there is no need to use `$form.submit(){  });` simply use btn `.click` event for post form

Answer (score 1):

Try this code this is working, check the console after clicking on tr value is posted to index.php file..

```js
$("table").on('click','tr',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    $('#club2').val(id);
    $.post("index.php",
            {club2: $('#club2').val()},
            function(data){
                $('#response').html(data);
            }
        );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" id="leagueForm" name="league" action="index.php?cat=goal">
<input name="club" value="0" id="club2" type="hidden"/>
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-hover sortable ">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="0" data-sortkey="0-0">Club</th>
                                        <th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="1" data-sortkey="1-0">League</th>
                                        <th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="2" data-sortkey="2-0">Games</th>
                                        
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>

                            <tr value="Napoli"><td data-value="Napoli">Napoli</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="100%">100%</td><td data-value="1" class="sorted">1</td></tr><tr value="Juventus"><td data-value="Juventus">Juventus</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="100%">100%</td><td data-value="1" class="sorted">1</td></tr><tr value="Inter"><td data-value="Inter">Inter</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="3">3</td><td data-value="75%">75%</td><td data-value="1.33" class="sorted">1.33</td></tr><tr value="Roma"><td data-value="Roma">Roma</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="3">3</td><td data-value="75%">75%</td><td data-value="1.33" class="sorted">1.33</td></tr><tr value="Empoli"><td data-value="Empoli">Empoli</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="3">3</td><td data-value="75%">75%</td><td data-value="1.33" class="sorted">1.33</td></tr><tr value="Lazio"><td data-value="Lazio">Lazio</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Palermo"><td data-value="Palermo">Palermo</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Sassuolo"><td data-value="Sassuolo">Sassuolo</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Sampdoria"><td data-value="Sampdoria">Sampdoria</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Atalanta"><td data-value="Atalanta">Atalanta</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Chievo"><td data-value="Chievo">Chievo</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Genoa"><td data-value="Genoa">Genoa</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Carpi"><td data-value="Carpi">Carpi</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Verona"><td data-value="Verona">Verona</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="2">2</td><td data-value="50%">50%</td><td data-value="2" class="sorted">2</td></tr><tr value="Fiorentina"><td data-value="Fiorentina">Fiorentina</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="1">1</td><td data-value="25%">25%</td><td data-value="4" class="sorted">4</td></tr><tr value="Torino"><td data-value="Torino">Torino</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="1">1</td><td data-value="25%">25%</td><td data-value="4" class="sorted">4</td></tr><tr value="Bologna"><td data-value="Bologna">Bologna</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="1">1</td><td data-value="25%">25%</td><td data-value="4" class="sorted">4</td></tr><tr value="Udinese"><td data-value="Udinese">Udinese</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="1">1</td><td data-value="25%">25%</td><td data-value="4" class="sorted">4</td></tr><tr value="Milan"><td data-value="Milan">Milan</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="0">0</td><td data-value="0%">0%</td><td data-value="8" class="sorted">8</td></tr><tr value="Frosinone"><td data-value="Fclub2rosinone">Frosinone</td><td data-value="Team">Team</td><td data-value="4">4</td><td data-value="0">0</td><td data-value="0%">0%</td><td data-value="8" class="sorted">8</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

In index.php file use

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['club2']))
{
   $club2 = $_POST['club2']; ///you will get your club2 value here 
   die;
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes its changing value on click in input, but its need to submit too and do not reload page.

Comment: why you want it to submit  ?? @user3307783

Comment: The result doesn't change in my $club value which is my mysql using.

Comment: you can submit all the form data data in your ajax request and get on index.php file and update in database, ajax is the only way to submit form data without reloading...

Comment: This part of ajax code can do that or i need more to do?

Comment: this ajax is necessary for that just use comma separated values that you want to send on index file like this `{ club2: "value", club3: "value" }`

Comment: @user3307783 If you think my answer is helpful than you can accept it :) Thank You

Comment: Its help me for 50% I got value in html, just need it to forward to php _GET or how its doing. Im not sure why its just changing in input form, Im junior developer... Please understand me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113582/discussion-between-manjeet-barnala-and-user3307783).

Comment: Which value do you want or send on php file?? @user3307783

Comment: I want club2 value to php

Comment: When I click on row its submit, but doesn't change it on table. When i open inspect and preview i see value. But it doesn't reflect on the page

Comment: where you want to change the value in table  ?? @user3307783

Comment: value of club names in another table same like this one.

Comment: sorry i can't understand what you want to achieve ??? ca you please explain in detail ... @user3307783

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the contentType. Replace $.post with as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {club2: $('#club2').val()}, // parameters on web method must match
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // <--important 
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.d);
        $('#response').html(data);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        //handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: The result doesn't change in my $club value which is my mysql using. Just in html when i use inspect.